# ValueError Scikit learn. Number of features of model don't match input

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am pretty new to machine learning in general and scikit-learn in specific.

I am trying to use the example given on the site http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

For practicing on my own, I am using my own data-set. My data set is divided into two different CSV files:

**Train_data.csv** (Contains **32 columns**, the last column is the output value).

**Test_data.csv** (Contains **31 columns** the output column is missing - Which should be the case, no?)

*Test data is one column less than training data..*

I am using the following code to learn (using training data) and then predict (using test data).

The issue I am facing is the error:

```
*ValueError: X.shape[1] = 31 should be equal to 29, the number of features at training time*
```

Here is my code (sorry if it looks completely wrong :( )

```
import pandas as pd #import the library
from sklearn import svm 

mydata = pd.read_csv("Train - Copy.csv") #I read my training data set
target = mydata["Desired"]  #my csv has header row, and the output label column is named "Desired"
data = mydata.ix[:,:-3] #select all but the last column as data


clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.) #Code from the URL above
clf.fit(data,target)  #Code from the URL above 

test_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv") #I read my test data set. Without the output column 

clf.predict(test_data[-1:]) #Code from the URL above
```

The training data csv labels looks something like this:

*Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Output*

The test data csv labels looks something like this:

*Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4.*

Thanks :)

Comment: I think target has less element than data which might cause the error

Comment: Yes you are right. But I'm confused exactly there.  But logic, my training set should have one element more (the results) . The test data shouldn't.   Is the understanding correct?

Comment: no, it's not your test data, it's your target.

In sklearn notation, you fit X,y when X is a tab of tuples or lists that represent your data and y who is the result, the target value that have to be found by the model

Comment: I gonna write an answer for you to see better than in comment

Comment: That would really be helpful.

Comment: could you just check len(data) and len(target)?

Comment: both are 2091. That's the total number of rows in my training  data

Comment: oh my bad. Is len(data[0]) != len(test_data[0]) by any chance?

Comment: cause you have `data = mydata.ix[:,:-3]` but you don't do that with the test_data, which would make a difference of dimension of 2 between the test and the training case

Comment: For the above python code, I am getting an error.  To make it more clear, my training data has 2091 rows and my test data has 800 rows. ..

Comment: it's a dimension problem, not a number problem. it's normal to have more data for learning, but you have 2 more columns in you test_data. `training_data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]` and `test_data = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]` is what you have

Comment: ypu would need `training_data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]` and `test_data = [[1,2],[2,3]]`

Comment: Thanks Whitefret for this. Let me dig this more myself. I will keep the thread alive for now. I understand what you are saying. This has something to do with my csv data dimensions.

Comment: or how you access it. do some print when you get data from csv to see if there is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a **Supervised Problem**, you have some data in form of (*input,output*).

The input are the features describing your example and the output is the prediction that your model should respond given that input.

In your training data, you'll have one more attribute in your csv file because in order to train your model you need to give him the output.

The general workflow in sklearn with a Supervised Problem should look like this

```
X, Y = read_data(data)
n = len(X)
X_train, X_test = X[:n*0.8], X[n*0.8:]
Y_train, Y_test = Y[:n*0.8], Y[n*0.8:]

model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
model.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

To split your data, you can use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) and you can use several [metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics) in order to judge your model's performance.

You should check the shape of your data

```
data.shape
```

It seems like you're not taking into the account the last 3 columns instead of only the last. Try instead :

```
data = mydata.ix[:,:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. With [:,:-3], I was trying to remove the result column (which was 3rd in my dataset).