# Evaluating the predictive accuracy of the NB model

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nltk

What am I doing wrong with using [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) from [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/) to check the accuracy of the naive bayes classifier?

```
...readFile definition not needed 
#divide the data into training and testing sets
data = readFile('Data_test/')
training_set = list_nltk[:2000000]
testing_set = list_nltk[2000000:]

#applied Bag of words as a way to select and extract feature
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(training_set.split('\n'))

#apply tfd
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)

#Train the data
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tf, training_set.split('\n'))

#now test the accuracy of the naive bayes classifier
test_data_features = count_vect.transform(testing_set)
X_new_tfidf = tf_transformer.transform(test_data_features)

predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
print "%.3f" % nltk.classify.accuracy(clf, predicted)
```

The problem is when I print the nltk.classify.accuracy, it takes forever and I am suspecting this is because I have done something wrong but since I get no error, I can't figure out what it is that is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it does the call to the accuracy method ? What are you trying to predict ? Try to add some print to see where it stops. Your classifier's fit method seems strange, it should be `clf.fit(X,Y)` with X the (vectorized) text and Y the labels of your training set.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead the [accuracy_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) of the [sklearn metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics).

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3]
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.5
```

I think you're mixing some things about Supervised Learning.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494212/valueerror-scikit-learn-number-of-features-of-model-dont-match-input/36502483#36502483) and try to understand the [top of this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html).

Your data should be in this form (before doing the Vectorization) :

```
X = [["The cat is sleeping"], ..., ["The man is dead"]]
Y = [1, ..., 0]
```

Comment: I tried this:  
print accuracy_score(test_data_features.toarray(), predicted)
but still got no results

Comment: You have to give the list of true labels and the list of predicted labels by your model to the accuracy_score method in order to judge the performance of your model.

Comment: Ok I am not sure if I am correct but could you take alook at my code pasted above and let me know if I am doing something wrong. So far, I have no error and can't figure out what is wrong. Everything works fine except the accuracy part. I have a text file that I divided into testing_set and training_set.

Answer (score 0):

Your have an error at least in this line

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tf, training_set.split('\n'))

You need to have your training labels and vectorized data in there but you have the original and vectorized data.

It should look like this:

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tf, y_train)

But you don't even have the label y_train data  anywhere in your code as far I can tell.

Comment: thanks. I later noticed that and I am trying to use the np.array(training_set) but It seems it is somehow a challenge to vectorize my text. When I do, this == np.array(list_nltk.split())
I get the rows but no column e.g (934567,) How do I really vectorize my text file? I have been trying this for a while now. So, I guess I just need to ask how to get the training labels using scikit learn?

Comment: Training labels is something you need to have in your original dataset. It is not something you can generate (with sklearn)

Comment: In that case my training label would be 'shakespeare' as I am trying to train a shakespearean text. Any complete example on how to train such text? I can't seem to find anything online to study.